# Get an average total based on form input - with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, forms, input, calculation

I'm trying to get an average for 8 form inputs and the best I've come up with is to divide the current total by 8 in my result (readonly) cells.  With my method, as the user inputs, the averages aren't correct until all 8 required inputs are entered.  But the good news is, I found [this excellent post][1] that almost works for me - except that this uses tables, which the script references this in line 3:

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
```

..but my form uses divs for each input field row.

Can anyone kindly answer how to adjust the script below so it works for divs instead of tables?

This is the example in the link above:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("input", ".kd1", function() {
    $('table tr').each(function() {
      // variables for holding total and count
      var total = 0,
        count = 0;

      // get all input fields and iterate over them
      $('.kd1', this).each(function() {
        // check the value is non-empty
        if (this.value.trim() != '') {
          // increment count for calculating average
          count++;
          // update total based on input value
          // treat input value as 0 if number parsing produces NaN
          total += (Number(this.value.trim()) || 0);
        }
      });
      // calculate and update the average although treat as zero if NaN
      $('.result1', this).val(total / count || 0);
    });
  });

});
```

and html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='result1'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='result1'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Final Solution - this works with DIVs:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="avcalc">
    <div>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='result1'>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("input", ".kd1", function() {
    $('div.avcalc').each(function(){
      // variables for holding total and count
      var total = 0,
        count = 0;

      // get all input fields and iterate over them
      $('.kd1', this).each(function() {
        // check the value is non-empty
        if (this.value.trim() != '') {
          // increment count for calculating average
          count++;
          // update total based on input value
          // treat input value as 0 if number parsing produces NaN
          total += (Number(this.value.trim()) || 0);
        }
      });
      // calculate and update the average although treat as zero if NaN
      $('.result1', this).val(total / count || 0);
    });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made the few changes required to get your Javascript to work with your HTML. This currently looks at *all* `<input>` fields on the page; you may want to alter it to just look at the ones related to the calculations, e.g. use `$('w-row input')` rather than `$('input')`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // If any input field changes:
    $('input').on("change input paste", function() {
        // variables for holding total and count
        var total = 0,
        count = 0;

        // get all input fields and iterate over them
        $('input').each(function() {
            // check the value is non-empty
            if (this.value.trim() != '') {
                // increment count for calculating average
                count++;
                // update total based on input value
                // treat input value as 0 if number parsing produces NaN
                total += (Number(this.value.trim()) || 0);
            }
        });
        // calculate and update the average although treat as zero if NaN
        console.log(total / count || 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for taking the time to look at this :)  I tried your revised the js routine and substituted to total line to show the average but got some odd results, especially after deleting a value then re-adding.  The TD version above does work perfectly, but as mentioned I need to lose the table (and reference in the js).  I've added a simplified routine in the original question, but in line 3 I've attempted to switch the td to div - $('<div>').each(function() { - but it doesn't work.  Do you know what to change it to to get the html to average (as the variable result1)? Thanks.

Comment: @PNEWest Can you be more specific about what you mean by "odd results?" What exactly was the problem? What do you mean by "deleting a value and then re-adding" and why did you need to do that? As for your revised `$('div').each()...`, there is no need to loop through each `<div>` and then each `<input>` within it when you can just loop through each `<input>` and be done with it, so I'd say your original code is needlessly complex.

Comment: @PNEWest `$("input#result")` will select the `<input>` field whose id is"result". Your `<input type='text' size='5' class='result1'>` not only doesn't have an ID, but its class name is "result1", not "result". I suggest you edit your original question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem, rather than trying to do this piecemeal in the comments.

Comment: @PNEWest Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70474980/edit) to show your current code that you need help with. Including links to external code is not helpful to future readers when that code changes or disappears over time.

Comment: Solution added the the original question above.